# Как сделать on_member_join/remove в Discord боте на Python

Tags: python, discord

Начал писать приватного бота для DIscord и задался вопросом, как сделать заставить бота отправлять сообщения о входе и выходе участников с сервера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Используйте события `on_member_join` и `on_member_remove`

Comment: Я не уверен, но возможно нужно включить `member indents`, чтобы события работали, если проблема в этом